# Handling files with Postgrest

Tags: postgrest

I am currently developing a webapp and a feature is for the user to be able to download invoices and product info in the form of pdfs.

Right now i am using base64 as text and sending it through the API. Is this bad practice, and if so are there any other methods you can use with Postgrest to send files?

Comment: here is a goodread about it - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB

Comment: Also check http://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/how-tos/providing-images-for-img.html. You should be able to send a binary response for your pdf instead of base64.